# pafy.get_playlist вызывает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, download

Почему возникает ошибка?

```
import pafy


def get_playlist(url):
    playlist = pafy.get_playlist(url)
    return playlist['items']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    yt_url = input('Введите ссылку: ')
    p = get_playlist(yt_url)
```

Ссылка:
`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-Sp30dZBoZ2nBqUkUB3C93YHiVJCp-GY`

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyprojects/yt_dl/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    p = get_playlist(yt_url)
  File "D:/pyprojects/yt_dl/test2.py", line 5, in get_playlist
    playlist = pafy.get_playlist(url)
  File "D:\pyprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\pafy\playlist.py", line 58, in get_playlist
    allinfo = fetch_decode(url)  # unicode
  File "D:\pyprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\pafy\pafy.py", line 67, in fetch_decode
    req = g.opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: `© Copyright 2013-2014` - сдаётся мне, это очень древняя библиотека, которая давно не поддерживается, вряд ли она ещё работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, библиотека `pafy` очень древняя, она не обновлялась с 2014 года и она не работает с текущей версией `Youtube`. Однако, внутри себя эта библиотека использует вполне актуальную библиотеку `youtube_dl`, которой вы и можете воспользоваться:

```
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    playlist = ydl.extract_info("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL634F2B56B8C346A2", download=False)
    print(playlist['title'])
```

Вывод (служебную информацию про скачивание инфы я сократил, оставил собственно вывод заголовка плейлиста):

```
Rick Astley playlist
```

Если убрать параметр `download=False` при вызове функции `extract_info`, то все перечисленные в плейлисте видео будут скачены в текущий каталог.